# Positioning element in a table to match other content

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Problem**

I have an html table with a particular  who's content can vary in size, sometimes the text is large and sometimes it's small, this leads to each table row varying in height which is fine.

However the  next to the one whos content varies in size contains two buttons, and they stay at the top of the cell.

**What I'm hoping to achieve**

I would like the two buttons to center in their cell in the middle to match the middle of the  whos content size varies.

I'm using bootstrap 4, I know you can use align-center but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Normally I would post code but it would actually be simpler to show a picture to explain what I mean.

[image: Table]

Now as you can see those two buttons I want to go to the center of their cells to match the ingredients column.

**What I have tried**

I have tried various methods using bootstraps align-middle for the  the buttons are in but they just stay at the top of the cell.

This may of been asked before, but each question I find on stack I'm struggling to find one that matches my specific scenario so if its been posted before please by all means link me and close the question.

**EDIT**

Showing the code would not make sense and would look out of context, unless I Posted the code for both the model, view, controller, and js file which seems like it might be over kill considering the question can be answered based on the context alone.

Comment: Without a [mcve] in your question we cannot help you

Answer (score 1):

Vertical centering is the default behavior in most, if not all, browsers. In other words, if your buttons are not vertically centered with respect to the lengthy text in the cell next to them, you've written some code to remove vertical centering (or you're using someone else's code that stops vertical centering).

I'd recommend opening your page in Chrome, right-clicking on one of your buttons that are not vertically centered, selecting "inspect," and then finding the TD in the inspected HTML that wraps that button, clicking on that TD element, and looking at its CSS in the inspector. The TD may have some kind of style attached to it that stops it from vertical centering. Remove or override that style in your CSS code (just uncheck it in the Chrome inspector to test to make sure you have the right style) and you should be good.

As an example, copy this code to a blank HTML file and then open it in your browser. All the cells should be vertically centered, because no code in this example tells the cells to behave otherwise. You can INSPECT the buttons in Chrome in my example -- and, more importantly, the TD that wraps them -- to see what the default CSS is, and that should give you an idea of what CSS in your own code needs to be changed and how to change it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First cell.
            </td>
            <td>
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>First button</button><br/>
                <button>Second button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First cell.
            </td>
            <td>
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
                Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text. Second cell with tons of text.
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>First button</button><br/>
                <button>Second button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm going to attempt this at the start of work tomorrow and report back what the issue is thanks for the insight!

Answer (score -2):

How about [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)?

<--Depending on the implementation, also [valign](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) for td.-->
As per the comment below. this option is deprecated.

In case it does not help, please post your code.

Comment: `valign` is obsolete and should not be used

Comment: @j08691. I've commented out my valign suggestion. Vertical-align is still an option to try.